# KeyError: 'data' when trying to read a json file into PowerBI using python

Tags: python, json, api, powerbi

I am trying to run a python script

```
def get_paginated_data(url, headers):
    data = []
    next_page_key = ""
    while next_page_key is not None:
        response = requests.get(url + "&pagination=" + next_page_key, headers=headers)
        json_data = response.json()
        print(json_data)
        data += json_data["data"]
        next_page_key = json_data.get("nextPageKey")
    return pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which takes a json file i got from postman to try and paginate some data using the nextPageKey that is provided in the json file.

However, I am getting a KeyError:'data' error. Here is the json response I got from Postman:

```
{
    "totalCount": 454,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "nextPageKey": "<hidden for privacy>",
    "problems": [
        {
            "problemId": "",
            "displayId": "",
            "title": "",
            "impactLevel": "",
            "severityLevel": "",
            "status": "",
            "affectedEntities": [
                {
                    "entityId": {
                        "id": "",
                        "type": ""
                    },
                    "name": ""
                }
            ],
```

I have omitted the data from each variable to ensure privacy. Any idea on what is causing the error? I have check some forums and I am unaware on how to get the "key" from the json file as I am pretty new to python.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the full stack trace please?

Comment: Does this work in Python outside of Power BI? If not, the Power BI tag is somewhat irrelevant, imho :-)